# Can't import turtle in Chaquopy

Tags: python, android, python-module, python-turtle, chaquopy

I want to use `turtle` module of **Python** in `Chaquopy` on Android, but just importing turtle as normal (`import turtle`) doesn't work.

I know that turtle is a `built-in` module of Python, and I don't need to install anything on my computer to be able to use turtle. It seems like in Chaquopy, turtle is not built-in.

I also know that I can define what modules to install, in the app gradle, but as turtle is built-in (most of the time), it can't be installed using pip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR**: Not possible currently and only possible if someone writes supporting graphics classes between `Chaquopy` and Android.

If you look at the Python documentation for [`turtle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) you'll see that the library needs:

> The TurtleScreen class defines graphics windows as a playground for the drawing turtles. Its constructor needs a `tkinter.Canvas` or a `ScrolledCanvas` as argument.

Both of those items require [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) which is the Python interface to the Tk/Tcl library. If you check any PC which supports `tkinter` you'll see that Tk/Tcl has been installed. That library is responsible for drawing stuff on the screen.

Android uses it own distinct framework for drawing things on the screen, and to my understanding `Chaquopy` only provides an interface between Android and Python code (with support for some libraries).

Since [Logo/Turtle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_(programming_language)) has a long history, it has been re-implemented a number of times. A quick search brings up this library: https://github.com/GolubevDenis/android_turtle which may suit your needs for Android.

Comment: Hi, I'm the creator of Chaquopy. All the above is correct, and `tkinter` and `turtle` are on Chaquopy's list of [unsupported modules](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#stdlib-unsupported). We have no plans to work on this in the near future, but now that Chaquopy is open-source we'd be happy to accept any contributions.